# Retrofit 2 disable encoding for post parameters

Tags: android, post, retrofit, retrofit2

I am beginner in retrofit...
I need send POST request with simple parameters

name        :  value

- login[name] :  some-name
- login[pw]   :  some-pw
- date        :  2017-08-28T12:12:12+0200

so, I tried

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(urlLogin)
Call<Login> signIn(@Field("login[name]") String name,
                    @Field("login[pw]") String pw,                          
                    @Field("date") String date);
```

that send to the server:

- login%5Bname%5D :  some-name
- login%5Bpw%5D   :  some-pw
- date        :  2017-08-28T21%3A11%3A57%2B0200

next

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(urlLogin)
Call<Login> signIn(@Field(value = "login[name]", encoded = true) String name,
                   @Field(value = "login[pw]", encoded = true) String pw,                          
                   @Field(value = "date", encoded = true) String date);
```

gives:

- login%5Bname%5D : some-name
- login%5Bpw%5D   : some-pw
- date            : 2017-08-28T19%3A59%3A04+0200

next

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(urlLogin)
Call<Login> signIn(@FieldMap Map<String, String> fieldsMap);
```

gives:

- login%5Bname%5D :  some-name
- login%5Bpw%5D   :  some-pw
- date            :  2017-08-28T21%3A11%3A57%2B0200

next

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(urlLogin)
Call<Login> signIn(@FieldMap(encoded = true) Map<String, String> fieldsMap);
```

gives:

- login%5Bname%5D : some-name
- login%5Bpw%5D   : some-pw
- date            : 2017-08-28T19%3A59%3A04+0200

please, help me, what do i wrong?
what wrong with date? why "+" are  disabled for encoding and ":" are encoded?
and why parameters name are encoded and how to disable this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have a similar question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65409306/special-characters-are-encoded-in-post-request-in-android-how-to-avoid-this

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71797393/1442734