# Special characters are encoded in POST request in android. How to avoid this?

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I am calling a post API with some parameters. one the parameters is

```
activatecode="aaaaaa$rr"
```

when the API call is made, it is sent as

```
activatecode=aaaaaa%24rr
```

The $ is encoded as %24. How to avoid this and send the special character as it is?

Comment: A similar question unanswered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925251/retrofit-2-disable-encoding-for-post-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I am using Retrofit 2.9.0.

I have this service :

```kotlin
interface WordpressService {
    @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
    suspend fun getPosts(
        @Query("page") page: Int,
        @Query("per_page") limit: Int,
        @Query("_fields", encoded = true) fields: String = "date,link,title,content,excerpt,author"
    ): List<Post>
}
```

Without putting `encode = true`, I end up with this request :

```
GET http://example.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page=10&_fields=date%2Clink%2Ctitle%2Ccontent%2Cexcerpt%2Cauthor
```

With `encode = true`, I get :

```
GET http://motspirituel.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page=10&_fields=date,link,title,content,excerpt,author
```

So in my case, adding `encode = true` in annotation solved my problem.